# Flutter : List item's data lost after navigating to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created `List<String> favId = [];` in my detailDoaPage.dart and add doa.id when the favorite icon is clicked.

```
onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      doa.fav = !doa.fav;
                      doa.fav
                          ? favId.removeWhere(
                              (element) => element == doa.id.toString())
                          : favId.add(doa.id.toString());
                    }),
```

But, when I navigate the app to another page and re-open detailDoaPage.dart, the favId's list data will be lost. Here is the preview of my app :

[image]

How can I keep the favId's list data even after I move to another page?
Thank you :)

Here is my full code : https://replit.com/join/xsppzeez-nabilrei
if you please feel free to edit my code and help me solve this problem

Comment: You can store the data in with sharedPreferences if you want it to be persistent, even when the app is closed.

Comment: @lrsvmb how to uses SharedPreferences automatically when we re-open the app?

Comment: check out this package, everything is nicely explained there; https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: @BillRei how were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely all page's variables will be lost when page been closed except those that are declared as static variables.
Have you tried to use static semantic when you define your list

```
static List<String> favId = [];
```

Comment: I tried to use declared `favId` as static variable, but the data still lost :(

Answer (score 0):

List favId = []; this type variable create App global.

screen open to check in intstate method.

if(favId.containes(doa.id) {
like show.
remove like.
} else {
like not showing.
add like.
}